# Is the homotopy of a primitively generated Hopf algebra still primitively generated? 

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras, ra.rings-and-algebras, simplicial-stuff

Let $A=\oplus A_n$ be a primitively generated graded Hopf algebra, where each $A_n$ is a simplicial group. This allows us to define the homotopy group $\pi_*(A)$.

Question: is the graded Hopf algebra $\oplus \pi_*(A_n)\cong \pi_*(\oplus A_n)$ still primitively generated? Here * refers to a fixed positive integer.

Here is some context. Suppose one is given a filtration of a simplicial group. Then $A$ is often the associated graded algebra $E^0$ of this filtration. Usually then, for a spectral sequence, the $E^1$ will be $\pi_*(E^0)$.

Perhaps this question or similarly questions is generally known, and I would definitely be grateful for any references around this topic.